# How do I reference another GWT module within an existing GWT project within netbeans?

Tags: java, gwt

As per the title, I have an existing GWT project within netbeans.

I've set up the libraries correctly so I can write code without errors, but the GWT compiler complains:

for each class I'm using from the other module:
**No source code is available for type *(whatever type it can't find)*; did you forget to inherit a required module?**

I'm sure I have the gwt.xml file setup correctly, are there any other steps I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

In my project that contains the module I'm bringing into another project, I need to go to Project Properties > Build > Packaging, and make sure that I'm *not* excluding **/*.java files. This makes sense as GWT needs the source files.